# Subdomain with www

Tags: iis-7, subdomain

I have IIS 7

We have about 61 different companies on our website and each company group has their own subdomain, like so:

```
group1.mywebsite.com
group2.mywebsite.com
group3.mywebsite.com
  .... .... ....
group61.mywebsite.com
```

Now a lot of people, when told to go to `group1.mywebsite.com` actually end up typing `www.group1.mywebsite.com`. How do I handle this please?

Ideally I want to simply redirect `www` users to their non-www counterpart.

I have no idea what needs to be done, searching for multiple subdomain doesn't give me any leads in google.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a `CNAME` in DNS, and appropriately configure the virtual hosts in IIS to understand that `www.group1` and `group1` are the same site (assuming you're using name-based virtual hosts).

That should be enough to point you in the right direction for further Google searching (or the ISS/MS DNS help system -- I'm not a Windows guy so I can't point you to specific places...).

---

What is a CNAME => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record
How to add CNAMEs in MS DNS => http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776292(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Dangit, I was in the middle of typing this...

Comment: CNAME will redirect to the correct name before making any HTTP requests, right?

Comment: @Chris - the CNAME will point your DNS resolver at the correct name (and thus the correct IP), but the HTTP `host` header your browser sends will be for the **CNAME** (which will confuse name-based virtual hosts). -- If it's IP-based virtual hosts the CNAME should be all that is needed, but making sure the web server knows both domains are the same vhost is still a good practice.

Comment: Hi, What is CName? as I see it, its an alias right? we have a dedicated server so no cpanel stuff, I manage everything from IIS. what is the cname in iis called? I tried googling, no luck. sorry to bother you with more questions.

Comment: @LocustHorde See the updates in the answer -- I believe MS calls CNAMEs aliases still but it's been forever since I sat down in front of MS DNS.

Comment: I see - in Windows when you ping a CNAME it shows Pinging (aliased address), but I see that if I open it in a browser it shows the CNAME.

Comment: @ChrisN the end result of a CNAME lookup (when your resolver library gets done chasing CNAME -> A/AAAA -> IP) would be the same IP.  Browsers (and webservers) also care about the hostname that got them there though :)